# Article for testing CSS typography

Tags: css, testing, typography

I'm making a content based template and I want to test typography on something that uses all elements like definitions, blockquotes, all headings from h1 to h6 (especially some less common elements like , , , , ).

I don't want to just have all headings listed one after the other but I'd like to have a nice preview of all elements in "real" environment.

I was thinking of making article that would use **all** semantic elements properly etc... but it's really pain in the ass.

So, if anyone has some link or resource to share I'd really appreciate. Of course, [this](http://www.yootheme.com/demo/themes/joomla/2012/nano2/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=4&Itemid=104) is not what I want, this are just meaninglessly scattered elements.

Comment: What do you have so far

Comment: @putvande just some modified text nicely arranged into sections and shit from wikipedia about Oscar Wilde :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, by a theme author for his own test.
2 pages of it:
http://wordpress.wesleymiller.com/blahg/2013/05/30/layout-test/3/
http://wordpress.wesleymiller.com/blahg/2013/05/30/layout-test/2/

enjoy

Comment: I was looking for more article like testing area, as I said, I have already found such examples, but for the lack of better answer, here's a voteup!

Comment: I'd also love to see a better sample which all in an article:)